# Insert an element to a list inside another on nested variables on state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json of this type:

```
object:{

   object2:[
    {
      test:[
       {
       }
      ],
      name:''
    }
   ]

}
```

What I want to do is to set the state of a certain test element and what I did was this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
        object: {
            ...prevState.object,
            object2: {
                ...prevState.object.object2[indexObject2],
                test: [
                    ...newTest
                ]
            }
        }
    }))
```

But when I do this the error this.state.object.object2.map is not a function occurs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    object: {
        ...prevState.object,
        object2: {
            ...prevState.object.object2,
            {
                ...prevState.object.object2[indexObject2],
                test: [
                    ...newTest
                ]
            }                
        }
    }
}))
```